# HTML table with 250,000 rows - a better way?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a csv file with 250,000 rows (Date, Company, Account, Amount) - exported from Excel. This is updated monthly.

I am looking to load the data into a html table to display, based on a search / filter - ideally with auto complete - searching the Company field.  This would then only display the data for that company.

250k seems too much to load into a table and then filter the output - so... what is the best way to go about this?  DataTables keeps coming up - but I don't know where to start with getting the data from the datafile.

Comment: seems like the standard solution for this is to use a database

Comment: I suggest you to use some server-side app with ajax to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a CSV file like this:

```
Date,Company,Account,Amount
2017-01-16,Jast-Bergnaum,Sales,94.31
2017-02-08,Upton and Sons,Research and Development,11.01
2016-12-21,Medhurst-Erdman,Business Development,74.67
2016-10-10,"Skiles, Hermiston and Goodwin",Marketing,77.0
2016-10-04,"Moore, Deckow and King",Legal,13.86
2017-02-12,Volkman-Jerde,Business Development,32.79
2017-03-21,Purdy Group,Accounting,33.18
2016-12-27,"Bernier, Rice and Toy",Support,4.73
2016-09-28,Corkery-Orn,Legal,41.73
2017-04-05,Zemlak-Fisher,Product Management,28.03
```

Then this code should do what you need:

```
let inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
let tableData = null;
let example = null;
let handleFiles = event => {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example")) {
        example.destroy();
        $('#example').empty();
    }
    alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})', [event], (data) => {
        tableData = data;
        createTable();
    });
};
let createTable = () => {
    example = $("#example").DataTable({
        "columns": [{
            "title": "Date",
            "data": "Date"
        }, {
            "title": "Company",
            "data": "Company"
        }, {
            "title": "Account",
            "data": "Account"
        }, {
            "title": "Amount",
            "data": "Amount"
        }],
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": (data, callback, settings) => {
            let fieldNames = [];
            let whereClause = [];
            let filterQuery = "SELECT count(*) AS recordsFiltered FROM ?";
            let orderBy = [];
            for (let i of data.columns) {
                fieldNames.push(i.data);
            }
            let query = `SELECT ${fieldNames.join(", ")} FROM ?`;
            if (data.search.value !== "") {
                query += " WHERE ";
                filterQuery += " WHERE ";
                for (let i of data.columns) {
                    whereClause.push(i.data + " LIKE '%" + data.search.value + "%'");
                }
                filterQuery += whereClause.join(' OR ');
                query += whereClause.join(' OR ');
            }
            query += " ORDER BY ";
            for (let i of data.order) {
                orderBy.push(fieldNames[i.column] + " " + i.dir.toUpperCase());
            }
            query += orderBy.join(', ');
            query += " LIMIT " + data.length + " OFFSET " + data.start;
            let returnData = {
                "draw": data.draw,
            };
            alasql('SELECT count(*) AS recordsTotal FROM ?', [tableData], (data, err) => {
                returnData.recordsTotal = data[0].recordsTotal;
                alasql(filterQuery, [tableData], (data, err) => {
                    returnData.recordsFiltered = data[0].recordsFiltered;
                    alasql(query, [tableData], (data, err) => {
                        returnData.data = data;
                        callback(
                            returnData
                        )
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    })
};
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
```

Thanks for the problem, it's been fun working up a solution. I've tried it with files with 300000 rows and things seem to be working fine, there's a slight delay but it's not huge and it loads the data really quickly on upload of the files.

Hope that helps. Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/syvzkn0k/). Just use the CSV file above to test it.

For a static file in the same directory this should work:

```
let tableData = null;
let example = null;
$.blockUI();
let timer = {
    start: moment()
};
alasql(`
    SELECT
      *
    FROM FILE("MOCK_DATA.csv", {
      headers:true
    })`, [event], data => {
    tableData = data;
    $.unblockUI();
    timer.end = moment();
    let duration = moment.duration(timer.end.diff(timer.start));
    console.log("timer", timer);
    console.log("duration", duration.asSeconds());
    createTable();
});
let createTable = () => {
    example = $("#example").DataTable({
        "columns": [
            {
                "title": "Date",
                "data": "Date"
            }, {
                "title": "Company",
                "data": "Company"
            }, {
                "title": "Account",
                "data": "Account"
            }, {
                "title": "Amount",
                "data": "Amount"
            }
        ],
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": (data, callback, settings) => {
            let filterQuery = `
                SELECT
                  count(*) AS recordsFiltered
                FROM
                  ?${data.search.value !== "" ? `
                WHERE
                  ${data.columns.map(i => `${i.data}
                LIKE
                  '%${data.search.value}%'`).join(`
                OR
                  `)};` : `;`}`;
            let query = `
                SELECT
                  ${data.columns.map(i => i.data).join(`,
                  `)}
                FROM
                  ?${data.search.value !== "" ? `
                WHERE
                  ${data.columns.map(i => `${i.data}
                LIKE
                  '%${data.search.value}%'`).join(`
                OR
                  `)}` : ``}
                ORDER BY
                  ${data.order.map(i => data.columns.map(i => i.data)[i.column] + " " + i.dir.toUpperCase()).join(`,
                  `)}
                LIMIT
                  ${data.length}
                OFFSET
                  ${data.start};`;
            let returnData = {
                "draw": data.draw,
            };
            alasql(`
                SELECT
                  count(*) AS recordsTotal
                FROM
                  ?`, [tableData], (data, err) => {
                returnData.recordsTotal = data[0].recordsTotal;
                alasql(filterQuery, [tableData], (data, err) => {
                    returnData.recordsFiltered = data[0].recordsFiltered;
                    alasql(query, [tableData], (data, err) => {
                        returnData.data = data;
                        callback(
                            returnData
                        )
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: Awesome - works well for 250,000 rows in the csv I have.  Thanks.

How do I modify the code to hard code the file to be hosted in the same directory as the html?

(Sorry for noob questions - high school science teacher teaching myself javascript and html for a project).

Thanks

Comment: works a real treat (once I worked out that I needed to load in blockUI and moment libraries.  Here's my working version: http://nerklegroup.co.uk/Testing/WG_fund.html  -- building it to display 5 years worth of data from Welsh Government.

Totally awesome and much thanks / kudos.  Now to play with Datatables to work out how to enable export functionality.    Many thanks.  Glen

Comment: Glad it helped - though you could just allow the user to download the original file, unless you want to apply the filters and search etc...?

Comment: Worked out the filtering - export what's displayed on screen -- so apply the filter, set the view to show all the results and export will only export what's on screen.  But yes, all the data also to be downloaded as the raw .csv file.  I'm going to blog about this when I get it finished - are you happy to be credited?

Comment: Of course! It was a fun use of the bank holiday weekend - might do the same myself, but merely in terms of performance of the different methods - looking at IndexedDB now ;-)

Comment: I've altered my recommendation if your target browser supports it, use [WebSQL](http://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/websql-bulk-insert.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to load the data into some database and look at using JavaScript to filter and to organize it for you.

Asynchronous Ajax will help you plenty with the auto-complete when searching.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your scenario is a client that wants to export an excel file, that they update constantly, and be able to keep it up to date. I have seen quite a few times, while this is not ideal I understand that the situation is not going to change a lot right now.

What I will do will be to use datatables, as yo say, and then apply that file as the source of the datatables. For that there are plenty of examples out there (csv2table comes to mind)

Answer (score 0):

In the html add a blank table...

```
<table id="datatable">
<thead>
  <th>Your coloumn headers</th>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Then in the javascript make it a datatable, (you will need to include the jquery and datatable libraries if you haven't already). You can then also load the data file with ajax. This example is loading a html source, not csv, but the principle is similar...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
    table.draw();

    // Use AJAX to append rows to the table...
    $.get(urlOfYourSourceFile,function( data ) {
      if(data.indexOf('<tr') == 0) {
         table = $("#applicant_table").DataTable();
         table.rows.add($(data)).draw();
      }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about using a combination of [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and PapaParse, using WebSQL.

1. Upload the CSV to the page using the [FileSystem API](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).
2. Parse the data with [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/).
3. Store the parsed data using something like the now depreciated WebSQL.
4. Use WebSQL to populate your Table.

Heavy hit to start with but after that, you're away.

Looks like a fun project though! Lucky you! :-D

I've had a play and come up with this:

```
let mydb = null;
let tableMetaData = {};
let inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
let elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
let width = 0;
let csvs = ["text/csv", "application/vnd.ms-excel"];
let intervalId = null;
let example = null;
elem.style.width = '0%';
//Test for browser compatibility
if (window.openDatabase) {
    /*
     * Create the database the parameters are:
     * 1. the database name
     * 2.version number
     * 3. a description
     * 4. the size of the database (in bytes) 14 * 1024 x 1024 = 14MB
     */
    mydb = openDatabase(
        "accounts_db",
        "0.1",
        "A Database of accounts",
        14 * 1024 * 1024);
} else {
    alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}
let handleFiles = () => {
    let file = inputElement.files[0];
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#example")) {
        example.destroy();
        $('#example').empty();
    }
    elem.style.width = '0%';
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        if (file) {
            if (csvs.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
                alert("Please only upload CSV files.")
            } else {
                mydb.transaction((t) => {
                    t.executeSql("DROP TABLE accounts",
                        null,
                        t => {
                            t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT, Company TEXT, Account TEXT, Amount REAL)",
                                null,
                                null,
                                null);
                        },
                        t => {
                            t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT, Company TEXT, Account TEXT, Amount REAL)",
                                null,
                                null,
                                null);
                        }
                    );
                });
                $.blockUI();
                let timer = {
                    start: moment()
                };
                Papa.parse(file, {
                    "download": true,
                    "header": true,
                    "dynamicTyping": true,
                    "complete": results => {
                        tableMetaData.total = results.data.length;
                        tableMetaData.columns = results.meta.fields.map(c => ({
                            "title": c,
                            "data": c,
                            "visible": c.toLowerCase() !== "id",
                            "default": ""
                        }));
                        tableMetaData.columns.unshift({
                            "title": "id",
                            "data": "id",
                            "visible": false,
                        });
                        for (let record of results.data) {
                            mydb.transaction(
                                t => {
                                    t.executeSql("INSERT INTO accounts (Date, Company, Account, Amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [
                                            record.Date,
                                            record.Company,
                                            record.Account,
                                            record.Amount
                                        ],
                                        t => {
                                            let query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM accounts";
                                            t.executeSql(
                                                query,
                                                null,
                                                (t, result) => {
                                                    elem.style.width = ((~~result.rows[0].total / tableMetaData.total) * 100) + '%';
                                                    if (~~result.rows[0].total === tableMetaData.total) {
                                                        clearInterval(intervalId);
                                                        $.unblockUI();
                                                        timer.end = moment();
                                                        let duration = moment.duration(timer.end.diff(timer.start));
                                                        console.log("timer", timer);
                                                        console.log("duration", duration.asSeconds());
                                                        createTable();
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                null
                                            );
                                        },
                                        null
                                    );
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
};
let createTable = () => {
    example = $("#example").DataTable({
        "columns": tableMetaData.columns,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": (data, callback, settings) => {
            let fieldNames = [];
            let whereClause = [];
            let filterQuery = "SELECT count(*) AS recordsFiltered FROM accounts";
            let orderBy = [];
            for (let i of data.columns) {
                fieldNames.push(i.data);
            }
            let query = `SELECT ${fieldNames.join(", ")} FROM accounts`;
            if (data.search.value !== "") {
                query += " WHERE ";
                filterQuery += " WHERE ";
                for (let i of data.columns) {
                    whereClause.push(i.data + " LIKE '%" + data.search.value + "%'");
                }
                filterQuery += whereClause.join(' OR ');
                query += whereClause.join(' OR ');
            }
            query += " ORDER BY ";
            for (let i of data.order) {
                orderBy.push(fieldNames[i.column] + " " + i.dir.toUpperCase());
            }
            query += orderBy.join(', ');
            query += " LIMIT " + data.length + " OFFSET " + data.start;
            let returnData = {
                "draw": data.draw,
            };
            mydb.transaction((t) => {
                t.executeSql(
                    `SELECT count(*) AS recordsTotal FROM accounts`,
                    null,
                    (t, result) => {
                        returnData.recordsTotal = result.rows[0].recordsTotal;
                        t.executeSql(
                            filterQuery,
                            null,
                            (t, result) => {
                                returnData.recordsFiltered = result.rows[0].recordsFiltered;
                                t.executeSql(
                                    query,
                                    null,
                                    (t, result) => {
                                        returnData.data = [];
                                        for (let i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                            returnData.data.push(result.rows[i]);
                                        }
                                        callback(
                                            returnData
                                        )
                                    },
                                    null
                                )
                            },
                            null
                        )
                    }
                )
            });
        }
    })
};
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
```

As I thought though, it's a huge hit populating the WebSQL table, especially as you can't do anything with the data until it's all there so you need to check. Once it's loaded though, it's really very fast - much faster than I would've expected and faster than my other answer using AlaSQL.

I guess it's a trade-off though. Faster data loading using AlaSQL with slightly slower queries or slower loading and lightning fast queries with WebSQL. I guess that the AlaSQL method wins though, the queries are slower but the speed of loading the data more than makes up for it.

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/vaahkx8a/).